# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast

Tags: java, mime, classcastexception

I am getting Class cast exception when try to send message.

I felt instead of taking that `javax.mail.internet`, it is taking jdk one jar.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart

MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) content;
              ContentType multiContentType = new ContentType(mimeMessage
                                                                 .getContentType());

   final MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) mimeMessage.getContent(); // line I am getting ClassCast exception.
```

I tried changing code this way :

```
final javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart) mimeMessage.getContent();
```

But it is not working.

Comment: The `ClassCastException` means that the `mimeMessage.getContent()` object you want to cast is not type of `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart`, so you will never be able to cast it to this type. I'm not familiar with JavaMail library but you should check what kind of object the `.getContent()` method is returning.

Comment: What are the jar files in the classpath? is thr any saaj-impl.xxx.jar?

Comment: Because you tried to fix it by using the different class in the last line, the problem is probalby here `MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) content;`. 
What IDE do you use, if any?

Comment: I am using Eclipse

Comment: No, I don't have this saaj-impl.xxx jar in my classpath

Comment: Hi Adam, I observe in dev environment this code is working fine but In testing enviornment it is breaking giving ClassCast Exception. In both environment, classpath is exactly similar

Comment: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeMultipart. This is also coming under rt.jar under JRE , it is taking that jar instead of mail.jar. I think this is a problem but not sure how to make sure it will take mail.jar not rt.jar